# They hadn't finished playing by 10.30. / They didn't finish playing by 10.30

Tags: past-perfect, simple-past

> They hadn't finished playing by 10.30.
>
> They didn't finish playing by 10.30.

I have my own explanation what the difference is. Could you please agree or disagree with it?

Past perfect helps us to say that 'they' not finished their game yet and we need to wait.
Past simple doesn't give us any information about the future actions. We don't know if the game was going after 10.30 or not. May be the game was interrupted with an important phone call or their free time was over.
Right?

**IF SOMEONE WANTS ANSWER ON THE POST, PLEASE DO IT HERE:**
https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/337434/they-hadnt-finished-playing-by-18-00-vs-they-didnt-finish-playing-by-18-00

Comment: The negative in the example is unnecessary and confusing. It is the negative that causes the appearance of the periphrastic "do". -- The question is therefore what is the difference between *They **had finished** playing by 10.30.* and *They finish**ed** playing by 10.30* -- Or, to generalise the question: "What is the difference between the past perfect and the simple past?". This is a question for ELL.

Comment: @Greybeard, I need to understand the difference in the mentioned context. The difference between past perfect and simple past I understand.

Comment: 1. You have given no context; just bare statements. 2. If you know "The difference between past perfect and simple past", then your question does not need to be asked.

Answer (score -1):

1. Past perfect helps us to say that 'they' not finished their game yet and we need to wait.

(correct: "Past perfect helps us to say that 'they' did not finish their game yet and we need to wait.")

At 10:30 the game was not finished, true, but there is no implication as to whether soemone should wait or not.

2. Past simple doesn't give us any information about the future actions.

This is true to a point; all sorts of logical actions can be inferred; from the following example it can be deduced that Klan activities went on after early 1928 in Alabama.

([Politics, Society, and the Klan in Alabama, 1915-1949 - Glenn Feldman · 1999](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Politics_Society_and_the_Klan_in_Alabama/giv2CAAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22was+not+yet+dead+in%22&pg=PA161&printsec=frontcover)) Although the Klan in Alabama was not yet dead in early 1928, it was experiencing considerable difficulty.

3. We don't know if the game was going after 10.30 or not.

(correct: "We don't know if the game lasted till after 10.30 or not.")

This is true.

Comment: Are you saying that if they didn't finish by 10:30 that they may have finished **before** that point in time, not after then? I don't know that that's an inferrible possibility here.

Comment: @tchrist No, not at all; my assertion is very general. In the particular case of finishing a game one may deduce the evident alternative that they finished before or after 10:30.  They may have finished by 10 instead, and that is before, or by 11 (after).

Comment: To the native speaker, not finishing by 10 always means not finishing before 10.

Comment: @LPH, If my explanation is not precise, could you write yours? What's the difference in their meaning?

Comment: @tchrist If someone tells you "they finished by 10" and this is not true, you have to say something like "No, they didn't finish by 10" or "they hadn't finished by 10", and the time could be before or after. That case must be included in the possibilities expressed by the combination "past + by".

Comment: @Sergei I did write mine, as far as confirming your explanation or refuting what I find erroneous in it (that is what you asked). There is nothing I can add, unless a new objection is raised.

Comment: A politician might say "No, they didn't finish by 10" to mean ending at 9.

Comment: @YosefBaskin I fail to see the subtlety you remark on. You mean it couldn't be said in any context of corrective answer? How is that?

Comment: @LPH: You could easily say "He wasn't dead in 1979" if you don't now whether or not he's died since. Similarly you could say "They hadn't finished their game at 10:30" if you don't know whether or not they've finished their game since. (In fact, that seems to me by far the most likely context for this statement.)

Comment: To me, the use of _by_ rather than _at_ implies that play was scheduled to be over at or before 10.30, but that didn't happen.

Comment: To my ear, it would be deceptive to say "didn't finish by 10" to mean *finished earlier*. The "didn't finish" part tells me it must have finished later if at all.